# Input/Output on qcow2 mysteriously fixed after reboot

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, kvm, qcow2

I had error `Input/Output error` when I was trying to do something on my KVM virtual using `qcow2` disk. I read about that its possible corrupted virtual disk, but I just ran `virsh destroy` and `virsh start` on my hypervisor, and now it works fine.

I wanted to ask is there possibility to track cause of this problem, or is evidence lost due to restarting of system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like vdisk was damaged after system update, I fixed it with `fsck` after reboot went everything okay.